# Connection refused error when running selenium with chrome and firefox drivers

Tags: selenium, webdriver, ruby

I am running selenium tests with firefox and chrome drivers. I get a connection refused error when I run the tests in as a block

**Test  example :**

```
require 'minitest_helper'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

describe "Test Example" do

  after :all do
    headless.destroy
  end
  it "test" do
    browser.navigate.to "http://google.com"
  end
end
```

**stack trace:**

```
1) Error:
Example test#test_0001_test:
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cam_integration/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cam_integration/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cam_integration/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cam_integration/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:616:in `raw_execute'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cam_integration/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:594:in `execute'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cam_integration/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:100:in `get'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cam_integration/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:14:in `to'
    test/integration/signup_test.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue, and found a solution in this article: http://swdandruby.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/headless-gem-causes-errnoeconnrefused/

You have to specify a **different** display number for each browser headless instances you need.

So if you want to run at the same time chrome and firefox in separate headless mode, you can do something like:

```
browsers = {}

[:chrome, :firefox].each do |browser|
  Headless.new(display: rand(99)).start
  browsers[browser] = Selenium::WebDriver.for browser
end

browsers[:chrome].navigate.to "http://google.com"
browsers[:firefox].navigate.to "http://mozilla.org"
```

This will spawn two separate headless process.
Note that you shouldn't rely on random things and better find some kind of unique ids.

Comment: I wrote the blog post reference above. The way I go about this on my CI environment is just assign the CI build job # to the display using the environmental variable set by the job. Jobs are usually on different number iterations, so this seems to work well. The problems with using a random number are the off chance that the same random numbers could be chosen for multiple instances, as well as the difficulty in knowing which display was used incase you want to VNC in to the headless display and observe the interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this problem is to set `reuse` to **false** when you call `Headless.new` and let it automatically pick another display number if the current one is in use:

```
Headless.new(reuse: false)
```

For more information, see the source code to Headless at https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless/blob/master/lib/headless.rb#L64, which says this:

> reuse (default true) - if given display server already exists, should we use it or try another?